# Regex to find a repeating pattern in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, str-replace

Here is a sample string that I am working with:
`- - - some text followed by more - - followed by more - -` 
I need to find each occurrence of a `-` at the beginning of the line and replace with another character. So, if a `-` is to be replaced by `~`, the final outcome will be
`~ ~ ~ some text followed by more - - followed by more - -`

I have tried `(-).?`, which selects all the `-`. If I put a `^` to indicate beginning of line, I get just the 1st '-'. If I give the pattern as `^((-)\s){3}`, which selects the group, but then the group could be any number of `-` in the beginning, so 
`- - some text is valid` and 
`- some text is valid` and
 `- - - - some text is valid`

Comment: What do you mean by the "beginning of a line" here? The first word char?

Comment: So the repeating pattern would be `- `(with a space, or unique character)? Like `^(-.)+`?

Comment: `^(-\s*)+` seems close to what you want.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes the first character

Comment: @JMichelB, the repeating pattern is just '-'.

Comment: @PhilipBrack, thanks for the pattern, but when I put the string in regexstorm, the - - - is grouped as one, so the replaced string is just ~, instead of ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways: match any 0+ non-word chars other than `-` (`[^\w-]*`) from the start or from the end of the previous match (`\G`) and capture them (with `(...)`), then match `-` and replace with a backreference to the first capturing group (`$1`) with a replacement char (`~`):

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"\G([^\w-]*)-", "$1~");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CG%28%5B%5E%5Cw-%5D*%29-&i=-%20-%20-%20some%20text%20followed%20by%20more%20-%20-%20followed%20by%20more%20-%20-%20&r=%241%7E).

Or, match all 1 or more non-word chars (`\W+`) at the start of the string (`^`) and replace the `-` with `~` only there:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\W+", m => m.Value.Replace("-","~"));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/e8CCv7):

```
var s = "- - - some text followed by more - - followed by more - - ";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\W+", m => m.Value.Replace("-", "~"));
Console.WriteLine(res); 
// => ~ ~ ~ some text followed by more - - followed by more - -
```

Alternatively, you may leverage the variable width lookbehind:

```
(?<=^\W*)-
```

Replace with `~`. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5CW*%29-&i=-%20-%20-%20some%20text%20followed%20by%20more%20-%20-%20followed%20by%20more%20-%20-%20&r=%7E). The `(?<=^\W*)` lookbehind will only make the `-` match if it is preceded with 0+ non-word chars from the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Though, I do have to say, it is going to take me some time to interpret the expression! If you do not mind, could you please provide more explanation?

Comment: I actually gave a descriptive explanation to each regex. A non-word char is any char other than letter, digit, `_` and some other rare chars. BTW, the first regex will work even in PCRE - see [the regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RCvvfw/1). The `\G` anchor matches the start of string or end of the previous match position. `[^\w-]*` matches zero or more chars other than word and `-` chars. The `^\W+` is basic - start of string (`^`) followed with 1+ non-word chars. The `(?<=^\W*)-` is explained.

Comment: I can look it up documentation @Wiktor, but if you add a small note on it, that will be very helpful. I am still learning regex..

Comment: I added the regex bits to the descriptions.

Comment: Hello Wiktor, what would the m.Value.Replace look like if I actually wanted to replace the '-' with \u2013, i.e a utf-8 character EN DASH?

Comment: @user1807337 `.Replace("-", "\u2013")`

Comment: Oh that was easy, regexstorm does not handle it, so I thought it will not work. Thanks